# Group works on topological space

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, quotient-spaces

I have to prove that if discrete and finite group G works on topological Hausdorff space X

$ \varphi :G \times X \rightarrow X 
$
and $ \varphi $ is cotinuous function, then $ X / G $ is also a Hausdorff space, where $ X / G $ is  a topological space with a topology given by an orbit relation.

I only need a small hint, because it seems to be very easy, although I can't do it.Thank youfor all your answers.

Comment: 'works':) called 'acts'

Comment: Consider two different points of $X/G$. Can they be in the same class? If they are not, can you find open sets that separate them? You might need to consider intersections, is the intersection an open set?

Comment: "Can they be in the same class?" no, obviously.
"If they are not, can you find open sets that separate them"

That's exactly what I don't know how to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two different points, $Gx$ and $Gy$ of $X/G$ where $x,y\in X$. 
 
So these are $2$ times $|G|$ pieces of points, each distinct. 
 
Since $X$ is Hausdorff, all these points can be separated from all the other ones by an open neighborhood. 
...

Comment: Ok, so I can find two open separate sets in X you mentioned and since $ \varphi $ is open then we get two open sets in quotient space.But how can I show that they don't have any common points? It is posiible that those two separate open sets have two points which are in a 
relation and thus their image is one point.

Additionaly once I find those two sets let's say- $U,V$  you mentioned I can show that if :
 $ \pi :X \rightarrow X/G $ 
either:
$ \pi(U) $ and $ \pi(V) $ have infinte intersection or I can find subsets of U i V, which have empty intersection in the image.

Comment: The hard thing to prove is that given $x \in U \subset X$ and $y \in V \subset X$ with $U \cap V = \emptyset$, you get $GU \cap V = \emptyset$.

Comment: So, we have $2|G|$ points $g_0x,\,g_1x,\dots,\ g_0y,\,g_1y,\dots$ with totally disjoint open nbds, say $U_0,U_1,\dots;\ V_0,V_1,\dots$. Assume $g_0=id$, Now take the intersections $U_0\cap g_1^{-1}U_1\cap g_2^{-1}U_2\cap\dots$ and the same with $V_i$'s.